# Alternate color of text based on background so its easier to read

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a piece of text that is on light background but overlaps on dark background as well. Text color and dark background color are the same
When it overlaps the dark background, I want the text color of that area to change in light bg color.

The text overlapping the background is the same color as bg so it's unable to be read. I want to change color of the overlapping part of text to `var(--lightest-bg)` as it's the main bg color. The dark bg color is a background image (svg)
[image: MOBILE VIEW]

Here's what the background image is.
[image: SVG]

svg background code

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
 <path fill="#1B262C" fill-opacity="1" 
d="M0,128L40,133.3C80,139,160,149,240,144C320,139,400,117,480,96C560,75,640,53,720,64C800,75,880,117,960,122.7C1040,128,1120,96,1200,80C1280,64,1360,64,1400,64L1440,64L1440,0L1400,0C1360,0,1280,0,1200,0C1120,0,1040,0,960,0C880,0,800,0,720,0C640,0,560,0,480,0C400,0,320,0,240,0C160,0,80,0,40,0L0,0Z"></path>
</svg>
```

```html
      <main
        className="flex flex-col justify-center min-h-screen"
        id="guest-index"
      >
        <div className="container mx-auto px-3">
          <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold mb-3 logo">Sanctum</h1>
          <p className="text-xl mb-3">
            Discuss anything with anyone on the internet.
          </p>
          <p className="text-xl mb-3">New Here?</p>
          <Link to="register" className="btn">
            Create an account
          </Link>
        </div>
      </main>
```

```css
:root {
  --dark-blue: #1b262c;
  --blue: #0f4c75;
  --light-blue: #3282b8;
  --lighter-blue: #bbe1fa;
  --lightest-blue: #e1f3ff;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--lightest-blue);
  background-image: url("/svg/bg.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: var(--dark-blue);
}

#guest-index .logo {
  color: var(--lightest-blue);
}
```

I'm unsure how to deal with this.
Also I don't care about supported IE at the moment.

Comment: @Pterrat  you can do it using CSS background-clip.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks a lot, I learn something today :)

Comment: Just to note that the info now added to the question changes the problem a bit - the original was a simple diagonal change in color, the actual requirement is for a 'wavy' SVG background.

Comment: Yeah, lack of details, my bad. @AHaworth

Comment: Would it be possible to see the svg - not a png version of it?

Comment: @AHaworth I've updated the question with the code of svg

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to 'cut out' the text with background-clip so if you make the background the reverse of your final background in terms of colors, and then put a 'real' background on (this snippet uses a before pseudo element to do that) you can do it all in CSS.

I don't know exactly how you are drawing the diagonal background so you will have to adjust for that, this snippet just uses a 45deg slope to give the idea.

```css
:root {
  --dark-blue: #1b262c;
  --lightest-blue: #e1f3ff;
}

.text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--lightest-blue) 0% 50%, var(--dark-blue) 50% 100%) no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 76px;
  background: red linear-gradient(45deg, var(--dark-blue) 0 50%, var(--lightest-blue) 50% 100%) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="text">Sanctum</div>
```

**UPDATE**
The required background is actually an SVG image which has now been added to the question.

This snippet works in the same way as the version above except the linear-gradients are removed and the SVG used instead.

The trick here is to set the fill of the two background-images to be the required colors.

This snippet is a pure CSS/HTML example without tailwind etc. You will need to alter it so that things are positioned as you want them. The important thing is to have the two background images overlaid in the same position with the same size.

```css
:root {
  --dark-blue: #1b262c;
  --lightest-blue: #e1f3ff;
}

.text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1440 320' id='bg'%3E%3Cpath fill-opacity='1' fill='%231b262c'%0Ad='M0,128L40,133.3C80,139,160,149,240,144C320,139,400,117,480,96C560,75,640,53,720,64C800,75,880,117,960,122.7C1040,128,1120,96,1200,80C1280,64,1360,64,1400,64L1440,64L1440,0L1400,0C1360,0,1280,0,1200,0C1120,0,1040,0,960,0C880,0,800,0,720,0C640,0,560,0,480,0C400,0,320,0,240,0C160,0,80,0,40,0L0,0Z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-color: var(--lightest-blue);
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 76px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1440 320' id='bg'%3E%3Cpath fill-opacity='1' fill='%23e1f3ff'%0Ad='M0,128L40,133.3C80,139,160,149,240,144C320,139,400,117,480,96C560,75,640,53,720,64C800,75,880,117,960,122.7C1040,128,1120,96,1200,80C1280,64,1360,64,1400,64L1440,64L1440,0L1400,0C1360,0,1280,0,1200,0C1120,0,1040,0,960,0C880,0,800,0,720,0C640,0,560,0,480,0C400,0,320,0,240,0C160,0,80,0,40,0L0,0Z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-color: var(--dark-blue);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Sanctum</div>
```

Note: the two svgs could be brought in from files if you prefer, each with the correct fill color. As I've put them inline they had to be data encoded to be correct as urls.

Comment: Although this works, that's not the expected outcome. The background behind the text can change it's position according to screen size.
As for the background image, it's an svg

Comment: Could you put more detail into your question - the SVG and how it is positioned in relation to the text. It should be possible to get the same technique to work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've added more details into the question as well as the actual svg and a mobile view screenshot

Comment: Thanks, I've added an example using the SVG as backgrounds. I haven't used all your HTML as I don't know tailwind etc sufficiently so you will need to alter what's here to fit into your structure.